# Insert data with new fields OR update conditionally using updateOne mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document with format like this:

```
{
  "f1": "v1",
  "f2": {
     "id": 1,
     "sub": "subv",
     "updatedAt": 123
   }
}
```

I have an another source that give me a `inputf2` object.
I want to write an upsert query to find document with matching filter `{"f2.id": inputf2.id}` . I̶f̶ ̶f̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶f̶2̶.̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶d̶A̶t̶ ̶<̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶f̶2̶.̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶d̶A̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶w̶h̶o̶l̶e̶ ̶f̶2̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶f̶2̶.̶ ̶O̶t̶h̶e̶r̶w̶i̶s̶e̶,̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶e̶r̶t̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶d̶o̶c̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶f̶i̶e̶l̶d̶ ̶f̶1̶ ̶(̶v̶1̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶h̶a̶r̶d̶c̶o̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶)̶.

Edit clearer logic:

- If **found the id** AND **f2.updatedAt < inputf2.updatedAt** => update whole f2 to inputf2.
- If **found the id** AND **f2.updatedAt >= inputf2.updatedAt** => do nothing (no update f2, no create new document).
- If **not found the id** => create new document with new field f1 (v1 is a hardcoded value)

Example:

**Input**:

```
{"id": 1,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 100}
```

Because 100 < 123. id = 1 will not be updated. **Output**:

```
{
  "f1": "v1",
  "f2": {"id": 1,"sub": "subv","updatedAt": 123}
}
```

**Input**:

```
{"id": 1,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 150}
```

Because 150 > 123. id = 1 will be updated. **Output**:

```
{
  "f1": "v1",
  "f2": {"id": 1,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 150}
}
```

**Input**:

```
{"id": 2,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 100}
```

Because input id = 2 is not found in db. It will be inserted whatever `updatedAt` is. **Output**:

```
{
  "f1": "v1",
  "f2": {"id": 1,"sub": "subv","updatedAt": 123}
},
{
  "f1": "v1",
  "f2": {"id": 2,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 100}
}
```

I tried with both 2 types of update, update document or update aggregattion pipeline, but seem that any of them fit my requirement.

**With update document**

I can use `$setOnInsert` but can't set `f2` with `f2.updatedAt < inputf2.updatedAt` condition:

```
db.collection.update({
  "f2.id": "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    // Can not check updatedAt = 100 < 123 and then do nothing
    "f2": {
      "id": 1
      "sub": "newsubv",
      "updatedAt": 100
    }
  },
  "$setOnInsert": {
    "f1": "v1"
  }
},
{"upsert": true});
```

**With update aggregation pipeline**

I can update `f2` with `f2.updatedAt < inputf2.updatedAt` condition with a bit tricky by cloning `f2` to new field `oldf2`, then apply the condition and remove `oldf2`. But in aggregation, there is no `$setOnItem` function:

```
db.test.updateOne(
{"f2.id": 1},
[
    {$set: {"oldf2": "$f2"}},
    {
        $set: {
            "f2": {
                $cond: [{$lt: ["$f2.updatedAt", 100]}, {
                    "id": 1,
                    "sub": "newsubv",
                    "updatedAt": 100
                }, "$oldf2"]
            }
        }
    },
    {$set: {"oldf2": "$$REMOVE"}},
    // How to apply something like $setOnInsert function?
],
{"upsert":true})
```

I must use `updateOne` because there is a list of `f2` item and I want to batch update these items in `bulkWrite`.

*Noted*: `f2.id` is an unique field in collection

Can anyone help me to write query for this logic? Thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can write the query. Here is my solution:

```
db.test.updateOne(
{"f2.id": 1},
[{
  $set: {
    "f2": { $cond: [
        {$lt: ["$f2.updatedAt", 100]}, // time check condition
        {"id": 1,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 100}, // overwrite value
        "$f2" // no change, return origin value
    ]},
    "f1": {$ifNull: ["$f1", "v1"]}, // this can do the same as $setOnInsert
  }
}],
{"upsert":true}
)
```

Testcase:

Input 1: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LRRFPptmC4I)

```
{"id": 1,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 100}
```

Input 2: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vv7dMboGpa7)

```
{"id": 1,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 200}
```

Input 3: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D1bPgGpDKdv)

```
{"id": 2,"sub": "newsubv","updatedAt": 100}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as written. The question says: "I want to write an upsert query to find document with matching filter {"f2.id": inputf2.id} . If found **and** if f2.updatedAt < inputf2.updatedAt then update whole f2 to inputf2. Otherwise, insert a new document". In the case of input 2 on this answer, the first condition is `true`, but the second is `false`, i.e. this falls into the "Otherwise" and a new document should have been inserted. Nevertheless the solution does not create a new document in this case.

Comment: Ahh... Sorry for my confused explaination. The "otherwise part" is only for matched id part, not included f2.updatedAt < inputf2.updatedAt condition. The correct logic is:

If found the id AND f2.updatedAt < inputf2.updatedAt => update whole f2 to inputf2. If found the id AND f2.updatedAt >= inputf2.updatedAt => do nothing (no update f2, no create new document). If not found the id => create new document

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first method almost as you did, just with a condition.

Edit: But if you want to change `f2.id` in case of insert, you should separate the `f2`, like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "f2.id": 1,
  "f2.updatedAt": {
    $lte: inputf2.updatedAt // Here you can check updatedAt = 100 < 123 and then stop updating
  }
},
{
  "$set": {
    "f2.sub": "newsubv",
    "f2.updatedAt": 100
  },
  "$setOnInsert": {
    "f1": "v1",
    "f2.id": newF2,
  }
},
{
  "upsert": true
})
```

You can see it on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4k8QHet6rkB)
And you can play with the `inputf2.updatedAt` to be 100 or 150 to see both cases that I pasted here:

If `f2.updatedAt` >= `inputf2.updatedAt`, we will get two different documents on the db. The new one will have `inputf2.updatedAt`, but with new id, as this should be a unique id:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "f1": "v1",
    "f2": {
      "id": 1,
      "sub": "subv",
      "updatedAt": 123
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("625b1873cdbb97ce928d8898"),
    "f1": "v1",
    "f2": {
      "id": 2,
      "sub": "newsubv",
      "updatedAt": 100
    }
  }
]
```

Otherwise, `f2.updatedAt` < `inputf2.updatedAt` : the document on the db will be updated, but will keep its original id:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "f1": "v1",
    "f2": {
      "id": 1,
      "sub": "newsubv",
      "updatedAt": 150
    }
  }
```

BTW, there is no problem to use this method inside a bulk update

Comment: but your query will create new document with the same f2.id if input updatedAt = 100. It must be unique

Comment: Sorry. Now edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Hmm not really, the id is depend on input f2, i can't create the id myself. If f2.id is found, update f2 with time check (time check not pass, no update). Otherwise, insert input f2 as new document

Comment: But the id of f2 is the in the `match` part...So it is not unique before inserting...

Comment: As far as I understand, the `inputf2` has an id that is identical to the one of f2, that is on our db, that is the reason that we are matching according to f2.id. If I understand correctly, you want to provide a new `f2.id`, only in the case of insert, so this will be a unique value. If I'm wrong, please provide the db after both cases for two different `inputf2`, so I'll be able to help

Comment: Please check the examples. I just updated