# How to conditionally include CreationDate when making a bulk upsert ($setOnInsert with $set creates error)

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, upsert

I am a beginner with mongoDB and I am trying to either update or create a very large list of products. Products that already exist in the database will have a "creationDate" that I wish to not overwrite. When using the following code:

```
public AddProductResponse add(final String trackingId, final String catalogName, final List<Product> products) {
            
        final AddProductResponse res = new AddProductResponse();
        res.products(products);

        final List<WriteModel<Product>> writes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Product product : products) {
            final OffsetDateTime creationDate = OffsetDateTime.now();
            product.setLastUpdate(OffsetDateTime.now());
            final Bson filter = Filters.eq(Constants.PRODUCT_ID_PROPERTY, product.getId());
            final Bson update = new Document("$set", product).append("$setOnInsert", new Document(Constants.PRODUCT_CREATION_DATE_PROPERTY, creationDate));
            final UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);


            writes.add(new UpdateOneModel<>(filter, update, options));
        }

        try {
            final BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = getCollection(trackingId, catalogName, COLLECTION_TYPE, Product.class).bulkWrite(writes, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false));
            LOG.info("Bulk write result: {}", bulkWriteResult);

            if (!bulkWriteResult.wasAcknowledged()) {
                res.setSuccess(false);
                res.reason(Constants.UNKNOWN_ERROR_MESSAGE);

            } else {
                res.setSuccess(true);

            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            res.setSuccess(false);
            LOG.info("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
            res.setReason(e.getMessage());
        }

        return res;
    }
```

I receive the error message: 'Updating the path 'creationDate' would create a conflict at 'creationDate'' and I understand the reason laid out in the other [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50947772/11874990), but i'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this some other way. Additionally, below is the test that I wrote to ensure the functionality is achieved. I appreciate any help.

```
 @Test
    public void testAddProductListEndpointWithExistingProduct() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final Product p = getProduct();
        final String token = getToken(trackingId);

        addCatalog(trackingId, catalog, null, token);
        final Response addProductResponse = addProduct(trackingId, catalog, p, token);
        final Document doc = getDatabase().getCollection(productsCollection).find(new BasicDBObject("id", p.getId()))
                .first();

        final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product().id("p1").name("Product 1").creationDate(OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1)).categoryHierarchies(List.of(new Category().id("id1").label("label1").type("type1"))));
        products.add(new Product().id("p2").name("Product 2").categoryHierarchies(List.of(new Category().id("id1").label("label1").type("type1"))));
        products.add(new Product().id("p3").name("Product 3").categoryHierarchies(List.of(new Category().id("id1").label("label1").type("type1"))));
        final Response addProductResponse2 = addProducts(trackingId, catalog, products, token);
        final Document doc2 = getDatabase().getCollection(productsCollection).find(new BasicDBObject("id", "p1")).first();

        //creation date of existing product should not be overwritten
        Assert.assertTrue(doc.get("creationDate").equals(doc2.get("creationDate")));

    }
```

Comment: If the product is already in the DB, do you want to update other parts of it (which are not the `creationDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to upsert the products using a bulk and a list of products, so that each product in your list will be inserted if it does not already exists and will override the existing document in case of existence, but not the `creationDate` property that is directly under the `product`, it can be done:
If the creation date is under your product you can't both `$set` it under product and `$setOnInsert`, so if your product structure is:

```
product: {
    creationDate: ISODate,
    propX: 'a',
    propY: {propZ: 2, propT: 4, propA: ['A', 'B']}
}
```

Your code should be something like:

```
 final Bson update = new Document("$set", 'product.propX', 'product.propY')
.append("$setOnInsert", new Document(Constants.PRODUCT_CREATION_DATE_PROPERTY, creationDate));
```

Note that the bulk operations are written using your code, before being executed as a query. This means you can use a loop to update the `$set` part of the bulk in order to add all properties directly under `product`, from your product list to your `$set` clause.

You can see it works on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FAcJT6DKUxQ), in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896601/insert-data-with-new-fields-or-update-conditionally-using-updateone-mongodb) to a similar question.

Comment: Ok, so if I am understanding this correctly, I should explicitly lay out all the properties to be updated in the $set and NOT include CreationDate. So that it is only under $setOnInsert.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: I was able to get it working in small examples, but I actually could not implement this on my original problem. The Product object has more complex members like categories and categoryHierarchies that don't easily translate to a single $set document. Not the best fix but I removed the creationDate property until someone explicitly needs it...

Comment: For reference, it is an openapitool generated object with json properties. But I can put this as answered since you addressed the crux of the issue.

Comment: There are several options, but in the original one, you need to specify only properties that are directly under 'product'